# Create custom Date format in php

Tags: php

I need to update jira custom field through API.

```
"customfield_10003": "2011-10-19T10:29:29.908+1100"
```

According to jira `This format is ISO 8601: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD`

I need to create the same date format with PHP. Please help me to do so.

Comment: Please remember to do a simple GOOGLE Search before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Use date with the c format.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
>
> ISO 8601 date 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00

```
<?php
   echo date("c");
```

To convert a specific date, you use DateTime or strtotime and date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $strDateAndTime = '2016-09-29 14:15:50';        
    $objDateTime    = new DateTime($strDateAndTime);
    $iso8601Date    = $objDateTime->format(DateTime::ATOM);
    var_dump($iso8601Date);   //<== string '2016-09-29T14:15:50+02:00' (length=25)
```

Comment: I need format like this '2011-10-19T10:29:29.908+1100' only. which have decimal after time.